# Error in android studio while starting and creating a new project

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Android Studio worked fine everyday. But when i re-install my studio, it started showing an error when I create a new project and on started.

Error Message :

```
Illegal type at constant pool entry 92 in class com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor$3
           Exception Details:
           Location:
           com/android/tools/idea/gradle/invoker/GradleTasksExecutor$3.fun(Lorg/gradle/tooling/ProjectConnection;)Ljava/lang/Void; @744: invokeinterface
           Reason:
           Constant pool index 92 is invalid
           Bytecode:
           0x0000000: b800 054d 2ab4 0002 b800 064e 2db6 0007
           0x0000010: 2ab4 0001 bb00 0859 b200 09bb 000a 59b7
           0x0000020: 000b 120c b600 0d2a b400 01b8 000e b600
           0x0000030: 0fb6 0010 b600 11b2 0012 03bd 0013 b700
           0x0000040: 1401 b800 15bb 000a 59b7 000b 1216 b600
           0x0000050: 0d2a b400 01b8 000e b600 0fb6 0010 b600
           0x0000060: 113a 042d bb00 0a59 b700 0b19 04b6 000d
           0x0000070: b800 17b6 000d b800 17b6 000d b600 11b2
           0x0000080: 0018 b600 192a b400 0119 04b2 001a b800
           0x0000090: 1bbb 001c 592d b700 1d3a 0501 3a06 2ab4
           0x00000a0: 0001 b800 0eb6 001e 3a07 b800 1f3a 082a
           0x00000b0: b400 02b8 0020 3a09 1909 b600 21b8 ... (show balloon)
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if SDK and JDK are still working fine, then you'll need to make the studio sync Gradle manually.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to be compiler problem. maybe easiest way is to remove every single file related to studio and reinstalling it again.